# Trouble with development environment on osx-10.8.2

Tags: mongodb, web, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, automake

I have been learning a little about a lot lately and in the course of doing so seemed to bugger up my mac.

Can someone please tell me what this means and how to go about fixing it?

> **$ brew doctor**
>   Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
>   `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
>   software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
>   compiling and linking.
>
> Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
>   Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
>   script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/php5/bin/curl-config
> /usr/local/php5/bin/freetype-config
> /usr/local/php5/bin/icu-config
> /usr/local/php5/bin/libmcrypt-config
> /usr/local/php5/bin/libpng-config
> /usr/local/php5/bin/libpng12-config
> /usr/local/php5/bin/php-config
> /usr/local/php5/bin/xml2-config
> /usr/local/php5/bin/xslt-config
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-config
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
> ```
>
> Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
>   If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected dylibs:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
> /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.4.4.8.dylib
> /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
> ```
>
> Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
>   If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected .la files:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.la
> /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.la
> /usr/local/lib/libpng15.la
> ```
>
> Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
>   If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected .pc files:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpng15.pc
> ```
>
> Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
>   If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected static libraries:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a
> /usr/local/lib/libpng15.a
> ```
>
> Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
>   Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
>   those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
>
> ```
> automake
> mongodb
> node
> ```

Comment: I fixed all the un-linked kegs, when I figure out what the rest means I will post if no answer is provided by then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got my system ready to roar by manually going and fixing everything homebrew complained about. I removed all the extra config files, .pc, .la and .dylib files. Then I brew linked automake, mongodb, and node.